# My Firebase console language has switched to Russian

Tags: firebase, internationalization, locale, firebase-console

The Firebase console I'm using has gone Russian.

My languages list doesn't include Russian on `myaccount.google.com`.

Based on the Firebase [FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq)'s "How is my Firebase console language determined?" section, this is the only thing that matters.

Only one of my Firebase console is affected.

[image]

I don't speak Russian, I didn't play with locales for development, I've never ever used a Russian friend's computer, I wasn't ever in Russia.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default language by adding `hl=en` to the end of the URL, so https://console.firebase.google.com/?hl=en. See [How to change language default in Firebase console web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43970866/how-to-change-language-default-in-firebase-console-web)

If it repeats selecting to the wrong language, please [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).